# What might be causing an incoherent output from my T-SQL query when using this specific filter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SSMS` and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT
...
FROM VIEW1

WHERE [ArrivalDate] BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2018-11-30'
AND ([Reason For Stay] = 'SINGL' AND [Total Guest] = 2 AND [Sum of Child] = 0)
AND [Booking type] = 'FIT'
```

The above query outputs **250** records.

Adding the following filter at the end of the query outputs **30** records:

```
AND [Title] = 'MR&MRS'
```

When I change the above filter to:

```
AND [Title] <> 'MR&MRS'
```

I am expecting to get **220** records (which is obvious) but the query outputs **188** records!

Under the 'Messages' tab in `SSMS`, I get the following:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

What might be going on here? And how do I correct my T-SQL query to get **220** records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to handle `NULLs`:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT
...
FROM VIEW1

WHERE [ArrivalDate] BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2018-11-30'
AND ([Reason For Stay] = 'SINGL' AND [Total Guest] = 2 AND [Sum of Child] = 0)
AND [Booking type] = 'FIT'
AND ([Title] <> 'MR&MRS' OR [Title] IS NULL)
                             -- here
```

Related: [The Three-Valued Logic of SQL](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic#comparison-to-null)

Answer (score 3):

This is expected, since *special* behavior when comparing to `null` values:

Any comparison to `null` value evalutes to `unknown`, which excludes record from result.

You can rea more here: [Three valued logic in SQL](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic). There you can read:

> Nothing equals null. Not even null equals null